# How using upcase_atom/2 in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Here is a minimal theorem prover in Prolog:

```
:- op(1110, xfy, =>).   % conditional
% -----------------------------------------------------------------
provable(F,P):-
        prove([]>[F],P).
% -----------------------------------------------------------------
%% 1. Initial rule: if G and D are strings [i.e. lists] of atomic formulae,
%% then G > D  is a theorem if some atomic formula occurs on both sides of the arrow:                 
prove(G>D, ax(G>D, A)):-
        member(A,G), member(B,D), A==B,!.

%% 2. Conditional on the  right 
prove(G>D, rcond(G>D,P)):-
        select((A=>B),D,D1),!,
        prove([A|G]>[B|D1],P).
```

to prove identity :

```
?- provable((p => p), Proof).
Proof = rcond([]>[(p=>p)], ax([p]>[p], p)).
```

I do not succeed to write some lines of Prolog code to get with the same input i.e.

```
?- provable((p => p), Proof).
```

an output with atomic variables in capital letters i.e.

```
Proof = rcond([]>[(P=>P)], ax([P]>[P], P)).
```

I am aware that

```
?- provable(('P' => 'P'), Proof).
```

is a workaround that solves the problem, but I'm searching a better solution, less tedious or more user-friendly.

Any help is welcome. Thanks !

Comment: This doesn't look quite right to me?? You say "output atomic variables in capital letters" but then you show something with actual prolog variables in it. When I run the query that you say "is a workaround that solves the problem" I still get just atoms, _and they are properly quoted_! like this: `Proof = rcond([]>[('P'=>'P')], ax(['P']>['P'], 'P')).` Are you sure you don't just want to render the Proof term differently? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Let me ask this differently: are you using this prover on the command line or somewhere else? If you are using it on the command line, it only makes sense that you leave the Proof term exactly as it is, since those "atomic variables" are best represented as Prolog atoms. If you are rendering this in any other way, you should probably take this term and create a string representation of it; I would use a DCG for that, most probably. But you should give an example if you want working code for a renderer.

Comment: @TA_intern  Your first remark is correct. Thanks for your attention.
With this prover https://www.vidal-rosset.net/code/jvr-leanseq.pl to which I added a pretty-printer for LaTeX (bussproofs.sty) which is probably yours, I get this:
```?- provable(('P' => 'P'), Proof).
% 10 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (94% CPU, 210735 Lips)
Prolog output : rcond([]>[(P=>P)],ax([P]>[P],P))
\begin{prooftree}\RightLabel{$\scriptsize{Ax.}$} \AxiomC{} \UnaryInfC{$ P \vdash P $}\RightLabel{$\scriptsize{R\to}$} \UnaryInfC{$  \vdash P \to P $}\end{prooftree}
true ```

Comment: https://gitlab.com/cspsat/seqprover-gitpod/-/blob/master/seqprover.pl  written by Naoyuki Tamura provides this utilities: the user types  ```p --> p``` and the latex output via the pretty printing can be something like ```$P \vdash P$```.